# select query to search a json text in apache camel

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, apache-camel

I am trying to run a postgresql select query to fetch json payload from database.
Json payload in database column is.

```json
{
    "transactionId": "a9S4Y044545F71UAE",
    "results": {
        "overall": "PASS",
        "documents": [
            {
                "documentId": "4d7cad3165a6-ce0d-49ae-bfd8-4d7cad3165a6",
                "document": {
                    "country": "Australia",
                    "type": "Driver Licence",
                    "typeLabel": "Driver Licence"
                },
                
                "extractedData": {
                    "firstName": "ABC",
                    "lastName": "YUZ",
                    "cardType": "Driver Licence",
                    
                },
            } ]
        }
 }
```

My query is like

```sql
SELECT doc_payload
from DB.doc_payload
where
jsonb_path_match(identity_verification,'exists($.results.documents[*].confirmedData.firstName ? (@ == "ABC"))')
and
jsonb_path_match(identity_verification,'exists($.results.documents[*].document.type ? (@ == "Driver Licence"))')
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException
There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{ (@/" == "ABC"))') and jsonb_path_match(identity_verification,'exists($.results.documents[*].document.type ? (@/" == "Driver Licence"))')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT doc_payload::text from DB.doc_payload where jsonb_path_match(doc_payload,'($.results.documents[*]. extractedData.firstName == "$simple{exchangeProperty.firstname}")') and jsonb_path_match(doc_payload,'($.results.documents[*].document.type == "$simple{exchangeProperty.doctype}")')
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain the problem behind the question/answer, this will give other people more insights about the problem.